# Why is the Jquery call is.(":checked") evaluating to true when I click some other radio in the same group?

Tags: jquery, html

Let's say that I have a radio button group with choices x, y, and other.  If a user doesn't want x or y, then they can select other and this will allow them to enter their own value in a text field.  The html code:

```
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="x" value="x"/><label for="x">x</label><div></div>
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="y" value="y"/><label for="y">y</label><div></div>
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="other" value="other"/><label for="other">other </label><input type="text" id="otherText"/><span id="error"></span><div></div>
```

The value that they enter will be validated(it can only be a number).  I am using jQuery to do the validation.  If the user enters anything besides a number, then the user will see an error message.  jQuery will change the innerHtml of span#error.  Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input#otherText").attr("disabled", "disabled");

$("input:radio").click(function() {
    var choice = $(this).val();
    if(choice != "other") {
        $("input#otherText").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        console.log("Choice " + choice);
    }else {
        $("input#otherText").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});

$("input#otherText").blur(function() {
    console.log("is Other Checked: " + $("input#other").is(":checked"));

    // If some other radio button is chosen, then I don't want to validate.
    if($("input#other").is(":checked")) {
        $("span#error").html("");
        var otherValue = $.trim(jQuery(this).val());
        if(otherValue != ' ' && otherValue.length > 0) {
            if(!otherValue.match(/^[0-9]+$/)) {
                $("span#error").html(otherValue + " is not a number.");
                $("span#error").css({"font-weight":"bold", "color":"red"});
            }
        }            
    }
});            
});
```

The validation is working as expected but my problem is deciding when to validate.  The above code validates when the user enters a value in the text field and clicks or tabs out.  This means that validation is done even when some other radio is chosen such as x or y.  So I added the .is(":checked") to other and this returns true despite another radio being selected.  Why is "other" evaluating to true even when it is not clicked?  Can someone shed some light on this?

Here is my code in Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Zycy/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to avoid validation in case radio with id `other` is checked, then do

```
if($("input:radio").not("input[id='other']").is(":checked")) {
  //your validation here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var choice = $(this).val();
```

This line in your code will always return 'undefined' to choice variable. add the value attribute to the radio input elements.

```
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="x" value="x"/><label for="x">x</label><div></div>
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="y" value="y"/><label for="y">y</label><div></div>
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="other" value="other"/><label for="other">other </label><input type="text" id="otherText"/><div></div>
```

Your jquery code looks fine to me. didnt look too much into it though. but the above definately needs fixing. You might as well use:

```
var choice = $(this).attr('id');
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I pasted from a previous draft.  All fixed.  My fiddle always had the correct code, http://jsfiddle.net/9Zycy/

Comment: @user1684636, Are you new to stackoverflow? Its always a good practice to accept an answer by checking it as accepted. This helps other users know what answer worked instead of trying to figure it themselves. Of-course, i also get a bounty for being so kind to point out a problem. Moreover, i still don't know what you did to solve your problem.This helps. :)

Comment: I didn't mean the problem was solved.  I just added the value attribute to the radio inputs.  My fiddle also reflects this change.  I am still having the problem with is(":checked") returning true for radio "other" even when another radio button being selected.